# Skip NAs when using Reduce() in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, na, cumulative-sum, accumulate

I'm trying to get the cumulative sum of data.table rows and was able to find this code in another stackoverflow post:

```
devDF1[,names(devDF1):=Reduce(`+`,devDF1,accumulate=TRUE)]
```

It does what I need it to do, however when it comes across a row that starts off with an NA, it will just replace every element in that row with NA (instead of the cumsum of the other elements in the row). I don't want to replace the NAs with 0s, because I'll be needing this output for further processes and don't want the same final cumsum duplicated in the rows. Is there any way I can adjust that piece of code to ignore the NAs? Or is there an alternate code that could be used to get the cumulative sum of the rows in a data.table while ignoring NAs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example :

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = c(3, NA, 1, 2, 4), c = c(NA, 1, NA, 3, 4))
dt

#   a  b  c
#1: 1  3 NA
#2: 2 NA  1
#3: 3  1 NA
#4: 4  2  3
#5: 5  4  4
```

If you want to carry previous value to `NA` values you can use :

```
dt[, names(dt) := lapply(.SD, function(x) cumsum(replace(x, is.na(x), 0))), 
     .SDcols = names(dt)]
dt

#    a  b c
#1:  1  3 0
#2:  3  3 1
#3:  6  4 1
#4: 10  6 4
#5: 15 10 8
```

If you want to keep `NA` as `NA` :

```
dt[, names(dt) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {
  x1 <- cumsum(replace(x, is.na(x), 0))
  x1[is.na(x)] <- NA
  x1
  }), .SDcols = names(dt)]

dt

#    a  b  c
#1:  1  3 NA
#2:  3 NA  1
#3:  6  4 NA
#4: 10  6  4
#5: 15 10  8
```